# How to add methodname in logging using runtime reconfiguration

Tags: c#, function, nlog, method-names, nlog-configuration

I'm working on a C# application, using `NLog` for logging purposes.

I have just seen the following in a logfile:

```
2023-06-08 11:15:58.1816 | NameSpace.ClassName | CheckMATCO | Check CheckFixstation ...
```

This is caused by the following piece of source code:

```
private static readonly Logger Log = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

public void CheckFixstation(...)
{
    Log.Debug(string.Format("CheckMATCO | Check CheckFixstation ..."));
```

This, obviously, is wrong (my colleague wanted to have the methodname in the log, but as he didn't know how to achieve this, he added it himself and did some wrong copy paste). I would like to see the following in the logfile:

```
2023-06-08 11:15:58.1816 | NameSpace.ClassName | CheckFixStation | Check CheckFixstation ...
```

In order to obtain this, I only want to use this log command:

```
Log.Debug("Check CheckFixstation ...");
```

This means that I need to do the following around my `Log` declaration:

```
LogManager.AlterOutputInOrderToAddMethodName();
private static readonly Logger Log = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
```

How can I do this?

Thanks in advance

**Edit after first comments:**
I've found a file, called `nlog.config`, containing the following target:

```xml
<target 
  xsi:type="File"
  layout="${longdate} | ${logger} | ${message} ${onexception:--- ${exception:format=tostring}}" 
  fileName="${basedir}/Logs/${shortdate}.${level}.log" />
```

How can I update this in order to add the methodname?

Comment: Method names should be included unless you disabled it in the config.

Comment: @shingo: thanks for your quick reply. Do you know where and how to disable this, so that I can enable it again?

Comment: In the config file, Idk which one you loaded, its common name is nlog.config or web.nlog. Then search layout or methodName in it. https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Callsite-Layout-Renderer

Comment: Notice the NLog CallSite-Logic will have less performance overhead when using `logger.ForLogEvent()` with NLog v5. There is also alternatives like https://github.com/Fody/Anotar or https://github.com/csnemes/tracer